# Are all emerging viral diseases of the past 100 years zoonoses?

Tags: virology, epidemiology

From my basic understanding: The viruses causing Ebola, Sars and Covid-19 are all the result of a zoonosis, meanings that the viruses have passed from animals to humans.

So my question is: Are all recently (let's say 100 years) emerged viral diseases, with potential for a global epidemic, the result of a zoonosis?

Comment: At least a lot of them. I don't like linking to Wikipedia for such matters, but they [have a nice list of sybtypes of Influenza A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influenza_A_virus) that should give you an example of how many variations you can have on the same base. From H1N1 to H5N1 and beyond, some of those variations were endemic, some caused pandemics. Some of those that stayed endemic had the potential to become pandemic.

Comment: In general, viruses don't profit much from their host dying or becoming too ill to infect others. Viruses that "rely" on humans to procreate are often not lethal - the lethal variants of the virus have a lower propensity to spread, so the less lethal ones are "fitter". Zoonoses have not been culled to be less lethal to humans, and are often much worse for us. We are "dead-end hosts" to them, We are best killed off so the viruses can spread to the preferred host, in laymans terms. Fortunately, we have murdered most mammals larger than us, so we are safer now than before.

Comment: @StianYttervik, this is a somewhat naive/narrow view of virulence evolution. Smallpox circulated in the human population for many thousands of years with a case fatality rate of 30% ...

Comment: @BenBolker There are certainly exeptions, I am making a general case. And, afaik (and googled right now) smallpox was a zoonoses, and thus is not a contrary observation. It's lethality was supported because it had an alternate (preferred host).

Comment: Basically everything is a zoonosis at some point. I'm not aware that smallpox had a reservoir host: what was it? https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/90636/is-covid-19-claimed-to-get-less-deadly-over-time-if-so-why/90672#90672 gives starting points for the modern literature on evolution of virulence ...

Comment: @StianYttervik: How would killing off humans help a virus spread back to (e.g.) bats? (And, given that evolution isn't intelligent/directed, how would the virus "know" this?)

Comment: @ruakh That was a bit of hyperbole, the virus certainly does not know this, neither does a mass of single cell pathogens have any desire or capability of making strategy. The point is that evolution tends to favor the pathogens that multiply, and being too deadly is not a favorable trait. Zoonoses on the other hand have other hosts (bats and rodents for instance) and strain as such is not limited much by being absolutely lethal to humans.

Comment: @BenBolker Rodents, I read. But I and a googled result might of course be in the wrong - I am merely an interested chemist - not a virologist.

Comment: @StianYttervik: Re: "The point is": Well, no, you made *two* points: (1) that human pathogens are better off being *less* deadly, and (2) that zoonoses are better off being *more* deadly. I'm only objecting to #2. It sounds like you're now retracting your second point (or at least, not interested in supporting it)? If so, then we no longer have any disagreement.

Comment: @Ruakh if (2) is how you interpret it, then yes. It's lethality is higher, but only because that lethality is no longer an important evolutionary stress.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To my knowledge, yes. A partial list of recently emerged/emerging viral diseases (I certainly could have missed some), with probable reservoir hosts:

- [Chikungunya](https://www.cdc.gov/chikungunya/index.html)* (birds, rodents)
- coronaviruses/sarbecoviruses (SARS [bats], MERS [camels], COVID-19 [?? bats ?? pangolins ??])
- Ebola and other [filoviruses](https://www.cdc.gov/vhf/virus-families/filoviridae.html) (Marburg): (bats?)
- [Hantavirus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthohantavirus) (rodents)
- [Hendra](https://www.health.nsw.gov.au/Infectious/factsheets/Pages/hendra_virus.aspx), [Nipah](https://www.who.int/csr/disease/nipah/en/) (bats)
- [Ross river virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross_River_virus)* (various mammals)
- HIV (primates)
- influenza (H1N1, avian) (birds/pigs)
- [Lassa fever](https://www.cdc.gov/vhf/lassa/index.html) (rats)
- [Mpox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkeypox) (formerly monkeypox: monkeys, [rodents](https://www.cdc.gov/poxvirus/monkeypox/outbreak.html))
- West Nile virus* (birds)
- [Zika](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1201971216310578)* (? ["a wide range of animals in West Africa"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1201971216310578))

Starred examples are vector-borne (so perhaps of slightly lower concern - might not fit your criterion of "capable of causing a global pandemic").

Omitted:

- older zoonotic viruses (rabies, dengue, hepatitis, ...)
- non-viral zoonoses (malaria, plague, anthrax, tularemia)

A [list of zoonoses](https://www.healthline.com/health/zoonosis#list-of-diseases); [another from US CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/media/releases/2019/s0506-zoonotic-diseases-shared.html)

More generally, the only other place an emerging virus could come from would be from mutation or recombination of existing human viruses. I'm not aware of such an example.

Comment: Corrections and additions welcome (I could make this community-wiki)

Comment: there are human viruses, it is just a virus that evolves with humans is not going to be that destructive, killing your host is always a bad idea and viruses evolve away from it. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14666532

Comment: @John evolving away from destructiveness includes cases where a virus evolved into something destructive anyway, but died out along with the population segment that was affected by it. So while destructiveness doesn't persist, there's always the possibility of a short-lived outbreak.

Comment: Should the hepatitis family be added to the list?

Comment: In the case of monkeypox, there was a [2003 outbreak](https://www.cdc.gov/poxvirus/monkeypox/outbreak.html) traced to pet prairie dogs, who were themselves infected by African rodents (two African giant pouched rats, nine dormice, and three rope squirrels were found to be infected), suggesting rodents are a likely reservoir.

Comment: @Mast: are there recently emerged strains of hepatitis? A *very* quick search suggested that at least hepB https://elifesciences.org/articles/36709 and hepC https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0153761 are pretty old.  Pointers to papers on emergence in the last century?

Comment: In theory could a virus cross over from plants?

Comment: to the would-be editor: mosquitos are the *vector* of Zika, not its reservoir/original animal host

Comment: Tularemia is bacterial, not viral.

Comment: thank you .....

Answer (score 24):

## Hepatitis D emerged in the past 100 years, without being a zoonosis

Hepatitis D is a virus which is able to replicate only in the presence of a hepatitis B co-infection.  It causes the same symptoms as the hepatitis B virus, but with greater severity and lethality.  In developed countries, it is rare except among intravenous drug users.

It was discovered in 1977, although epidemics of Lábrea fever in the 1950s were later determined to be caused by the virus.  Comparisons of known strains and the mutation rate suggest a common ancestor around the year 1930.

Hepatitis D is the smallest known animal virus (less than 1700 nucleotides), and is the only species in the *Deltavirus* genus.  There is no known animal reservoir.  The most similar known animal virus shares only 32% of the nucleotides of hepatitis D.

According to its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatitis_D),

> It has been proposed that **HDV may have originated from a class of plant pathogens** called viroids, which are much smaller than viruses.

Comment: Even if indeed this virus originated in plants, is it really true that humans were the initial animal target? That seems exceedingly unlikely, and there are other similar viruses that infect other animals as well.